# R programming: How to set while loop condition based if all required values in vector have been copied from sample?

Tags: r, if-statement, while-loop

I new to R and I'm trying to see how many iterations are needed to fill a vector with numbers 1 to 55 (no duplicates) from a random sample using runif.

At the moment, the vector has a lots of duplicates in it and my number of iterations being returned is the size of the vector. So, i'm not sure if my logic is correct.
The aim of the if statement is to check if the value from the sample exists in the vector, and if it does, choose the next one. But i'm not sure if it's correct, since the next number could already exist in the vector. Any help would be much appreciated

```
numbers=as.integer(runif(800, min=1, max=55)) ## my sample from runif
i=sample(numbers, 1) 

## setting up my vector to store 55 unique values (1 to 55)
p=rep(0,55)

## my counters
j=0
n=1

## my while loop
while (p[n] %in% 0){
## if the sample value already exists in the vector, choose the next value from the sample
if (numbers[n] %in% p) {
p[n]=numbers[n+1] 
}
else {
p[n] = numbers[n] 
}
    n = n + 1
    j = j + 1
}
```

Comment: `p` is right now a vector of zeros. Did you mean `1:55` instead of `rep(0,55)`?

Comment: My aim was to create an empty vector with 55 blank spaces, so that i could use it as my while loop condition. Is it better if I set it up as rep(1,55) ? Does this make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following is what you want. Instead pf a `while` loop on `p`, the `while` loop should search for a new value in `numbers`.

```
set.seed(2021)    # make the results reproducible
numbers <- sample(55, 800, TRUE)
## setting up my vector to store 55 unique values (1 to 55)
p <- integer(55)

# assign the elemnts of p one by one
for(j in seq_along(p)){
  ## if the sample value already exists in the vector, 
  ## choose the next value from the sample
  n <- 1
  while (numbers[n] %in% p) {
    n <- n + 1
  }
  if(n <= length(numbers)){
    p[j] <- numbers[n]
  }
}

j
#[1] 55
length(unique(p)) == length(p)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you Rui. However at the moment, the number of iterations that are required to fill the vector is the size of the vector itself.  I need to see how many times I should draw a random number (from a randomised uniform distribution) to fill in a vector with the values 1 to 55. 

What do you suggest I do if I wanted to get the number of iterations required to fill my vector from a randomised uniform distribution in a simulation of 800 times?